# The link to "linked questions" doesn't reflect all links

Tags: support, linked-questions

Taking as example the third most linked question: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/185667)

When we click on *"see more linked questions..."*

> [image: linked questions]

It takes us to this search query:

> [image: url:"http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/16065/*"]

But the shortlinks when we grab the "Share URL" are formed with `/q/POST_ID` instead of `/question/POST_ID`. If we insert another wildcard the results are different:

> [image: url:"http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*/16065/*"]

---

I took a look in the top questions in the [Frequent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent) tab and the difference of results is not that big, normally only a few extra links. (Curiously, there seem to be many more links using `/question/` than `/q/`.)

I'm not sure if this is a feature request (modify "see more" link to find *all* linked questions) or a discussion on the logic and inner workings of this functionality. Am tagging as [support](/questions/tagged/support) to start with.

Comment: This bug has been around for ages. I'm still waiting for it to get fixed.