# What is the correct way to request a [status-xxx] tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, meta, moderator-tags

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176188/help-to-reopen-a-question-apache-server-htaccess) is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). (EDIT: deleted now, must find better example) (EDIT2: Another example: [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176168/the-link-to-linked-questions-doesnt-reflect-all-links) should be [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced).)

How should I request a [status-something] tag on a question? I was thinking of using a flag with the "other" option. Is this the correct thing to do? What should I do now and in the future to request a status tag?

Comment: Ehm.. I'm not going to put that tag on there..  I always thought the [status-reproduced] tag was reserved for the SE developer staff, to indicate that they had reproduced the issue themselves.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well I am kind of trying to find a better example of a Q needing [status-completed], but I can't find one. Anyway that's not the point of the question; it doesn't matter if you add the tag. I just needed an example :P

Comment: It's going to be an interesting day when I see a question worthy of being tagged `[status-xxx]`.

Comment: @PopularDemand Any question containing "bare with me" would qualify, I'd think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, flag 'other' and leave a comment that you think the question needs the tag and why.